# How to typemap returned custom template?

Tags: python, templates, swig

I have a set of C++ image processing classes using

```
template <typename T> class PixelBuffer {... }

class ImageSource {
  PixelBuffer<uint16_t> GetImage() const;
};
```

Ultimately I want to map class ImageSource to Python and convert the return value of ImageSource::GetImage() to a NumPy Array. I am *not* interested in mapping the PixelBuffer template class itself since it mainly does C++ memory management operations useless in Python.

Obviously I need to typemap the returned type before I can even start creating the array. I tried many variation like

```
%template(image_u16) PixelBuffer<uint16_t>;

%typemap(out) image_u16 {
  $result = PyInt_FromLong(88);
}
```

However this typemap is never used. When I test GetImage() I always get a PixelBuffer object mapped to Python instead of 88. It seems PixelBuffer is automatically mapped because I need to "%include" it (otherwise I get "Template 'PixelBuffer' undefined").

How can I make sure that the provided typemap is actually used? Is this a stupid syntax mistake or a subtle mapping precedence problem?

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes:

- The class and method name must be given as ImageSource::GetImage
- Order is important; typemap must come before the type is included.
- I need to add `%ignore PixelBuffer` if I do not want PixelBuffer to be wrapped.

Unfortunately SWIG still requires a default constructor and assignment operator for the matched type.